# How to edit an existing android app so the name and icon of the app is different

Tags: android, xml, cell

Can someone please help me, i need to edit an existing android app so the name and icon of the app is different. Anyone know how?

I've tried editing xml, but im just not that good of a hacker, it would amaze me if someone could do this. please help.

Comment: android:icon="@drawable/your icon"
        android:label="your name" for application tag in manifest. makes sure you have a icon in your drawable folder

Comment: just to clarify, if by existing app you mean that app is on market you can not change that unless you upload it again but with different package name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the name and icon you have to go to Manifest.xml and where the application is defined you can change it's attributes like:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/yournewimage"
        android:label="@string/yourappname">
```

You have to put your image to res/drawable folder and define your app name at res/values/strings.xml.
For the name you can also put the name hardcoded like this:

```
<application
     android:label="thename">
```

but it's better to define it on strings.xml

I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy steps:

**FOR GENERATING THE ICONS:**

1. Create a new hi-res image that you want to use as the new Icon.
2. In Eclipse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + N --> Android Icon Set.
3. Launcher Icons -> Select your Project from the dropdown and give a name for the Icon. And then Next
4. Provide the Image by clicking the Image button. Make necessary modifications and click finish.

This will create a new set of Icons for your project (the app).

**FOR CHANGING THE NAME AND ICON**

Open the `AndroidManifest.xml` in Eclipse and make these changes:

```
<application

    <!-- CHANGE THE ic_launcher to the name you selected in step 3 shown above -->
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    <!-- CHANGE THIS TO GIVE A NEW NAME TO THE APP -->
    android:label="NEW APP NAME" >

    ....

</application>
```

Instead of hard coding the app name, you should ideally, create an entry for it in the `strings.xml`. For example:

```
<string name="app_name">NEW APP NAME</string>
```

And pass it to the `android:label=""` attribute show above:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```